# How to use Listeners in robot framework

Tags: python-2.7, listener, robotframework

Im using python 2.7.15 with robot versuon 3.0.4. I have a requirement to take only the screenshots of FAILED test cases. Some posts in stackoverflow says listeners must be used for manipulating test results. or is there a keyword for the same?

Comment: U just need to capture when fail test only right ?

Comment: Please fix the indentation of your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you're after but this is what I use at RF level:

```
Global Test Teardown
    Run Keyword If Test Failed    Capture Page Screenshot
```

Alternatively you should be able to do something like this in Python:

```
def global_test_teardown(testStatus=BuiltIn().get_variable_value("${TEST STATUS}")):
    seleniumlib = BuiltIn().get_library_instance('SeleniumLibrary')
    if testStatus=="FAIL":
        seleniumlib.capture_page_screenshot()
```

Comment: thanks for the reply @Lubos Jerabek . I Though using listeners was the only solution. But, you provided an alternative way by using the test teardown keyword. I tried and it works too. So, whenever my test fails i can use 'Run Keyword if test failed' option, and capture the screenshots. Thanks.